# How to check if two Box2d bodies collision / overlap at any moment?

Tags: java, android, box2d, libgdx

How can you check if 2 bodies(with 1 Fixture both) collide(overlaps)?

I know about the ContactListener that fires a method when they start colliding and when they stop. But is there a way to check it in any given moment? Like:

```
if(body1.overlaps(body2))...
```

Additional details, one of them is sensor. this is in libgdx.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062252/how-to-detect-collision-but-do-not-collide-in-box2d Completely inside another body: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27320/in-box2d-how-can-i-check-for-bodies-within-a-circle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply `setContactlistner` to your world object like

```
world.setContactListener(new ContactListener() {

            @Override
        public void beginContact(Contact contact) {

         if(contact.getfixtureA.getBody().getUserData()=="body1"&&
               contact.getfixtureB.getBody().getUserData()=="body2")
            Colliding = true;
            System.out.println("Contact detected");
        }

        @Override
        public void endContact(Contact contact) {
            Colliding = false;
            System.out.println("Contact removed");
        }

        @Override
        public void postSolve(Contact arg0, ContactImpulse arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void preSolve(Contact arg0, Manifold arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

The `beginContact()` method will always call whenever any body will overlap or touch another body.You can also get the information about the body by  `contact` object like `contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData();` if you want to do something with them.And when they separate from each other `EndContact()` method will be called.

Hope This helps.

Comment: You didn't understand/read my question, I know about the ContactListener.

Comment: As I said you can get the userdata of the bodies which is being colliding, so with the help of that user data of both the bodies you can take a Boolean or something and check it in the render if that Boolean is true then do your work.And false it in the endContact() method.

Comment: I don't know if this is a bug at current but endContact doesn't always fire.

Answer (score 2):

Just check if the contact you are looking for is in the contact list:

```
for (ContactEdge ce = body1.getContactList(); ce != null; ce = ce.next)
{
     if (ce.other == body2 && ce.contact.isTouching())
     {
         // Do what you want here

         break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Do not forget check, if contact is touching: ce->contact->IsTouching(). Contacts creating when AABB are overlap.

Comment: Although I did label libgdx, I forgot to tell. It is in libgdx and there is no getContactList nor other method in body u.u

Answer (score -4):

You can create the variable collision:
When equals 0, collision equals false;
When equals 1, collision equals true;

So:

```
if(body1.overlaps(body2)==true)
{collision=1}
else
{collision=0}
```

Comment: you didnt even understand the question